# MSVC: pragma to force rebuild of a file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, pragma, rebuild

Is there a pragma-statement for MSVC that causes the compiler to rebuild a file always - also in case it thinks it was just builded?

Comment: No, the build system doesn't look inside files when figuring out what to rebuild.  Your question is insufficiently documented to propose an alternative.

Comment: My problem is fairly simple: I'm using one single source file to build two different applications. The options the object used for generating this source file are slightly different. So when it is built for the first program, the second one will have some linker errors. Here only rebuilding this single object file within context of the second program helps.

Comment: Right-click the file, Properties, C/C++, Output Files, change the Object File Name so it gets compiled to a different .obj file.

Comment: There nothing can be changed...possibly this option does not exist in VC++ 6?

Comment: Ugh, always mention that you are using tools from the previous century.

Comment: Sorry for digging up this really old post. I think the real solution for you is to use different intermediate directories for your different applications. That way your .cpp file will be compiled to different .o files => You won't end up with linker errors => You won't have to recompile your whole .cpp each time you switch application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a trick that I use to achieve this :

1) Add a post build step command with something like

```
echo #define __FORCE_REBUILD__ "Include this file in a cpp to invalidate it at each compilation" > $(ProjectDir)ForceRebuild.h
```

2) Add a '#include "ForceRebuild.h"' in each cpp that you want to force rebuild.

It will only work after a build actually occurs (since the post build is skipped if Visual Studio decides to skip building the project).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is, and I'm pretty sure there can't be (barring substantial changes to the tool chain in general).

The reason is fairly simple: when `make` (or equivalent) is deciding what to build, it doesn't look at the *content* of the file(s) involved at all -- it just compares the timestamp on the object file to the timestamp on the source file. If the object file is newer than its source, the compiler will never be invoked for that file, so the compiler will never get to see the content of that file (including the theorized `#pragma`) at all.